# How to add <picture> around the fotorama__img on the productpage - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, product-images, image, gallery

We would like to add a `<picture> </picture>` element around the main image with class `fotorama__img` on the productpage.

How can we achieve that?

Comment: What is the reason behind why you want this?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? do you want to add the thumbnails? or just add the <picture> element after the main image?

Comment: We just want to wrap the main product image around a <picture> element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing the file app/design/frontend/theme/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

Comment: this will create an issue with configurable please check once

Answer (score 4):

Note that the image gallery script in Magento is heavily developed.
If you add a picture tag, you will have to check if the rest of the functionality (e.g. magnifier, fullscreen popup, etc.) works.

If you add the  tag in the `app/design/frontend/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml` file, you only add it for the gallery placeholder that exists before the photo gallery initialization.

Note that you asked about adding `<picture>` for a photo with the class `.fotorama__img`. This class exists after the gallery is initialized by `fotorama.js`.

To add the `<picture>` tag you should overwrite the `fotorama.js` file and modify it within the **loadImg(...)** function.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js#L2272

You should create a `<picture>` and `<source ...>` element by JS and add a $(img) object to them before the loop ends.

Remember not to edit the file directly, but to overwrite or extend it.

Comment: this ans make more sense to me

Answer (score 3):

I have found one extension that can help

https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_NextGenImages

https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_Webp2

Comment: Thanks Kushal! I know this module, but this also adds a lot of other options as well. We would only like to add a <picture> html element around the image.